# What do these rewrite lines mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

What do the following lines mean? I am sorry, I am a new learner of regular expressions.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %1/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule index.php?=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

After reading some [Apache rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine#Web_frameworks) documentation, I now have some basic knowledge, but I still can't understand some part of the above lines well.

`%{HTTP_HOST}` the requset domain

`[NC]` (case insensitive)

`L` (last - stop processing rules)

`-f` if Something_to_test is a file

`-d` if Something_to_test is a directory

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`  the requset file name

1. What does the `$`  mean in (`^www\.(.*)$`). All the URLs that are requested by the client are all beginning by `www.` . Am I right?
2. What's the meaning `%1/%`?
3. RewriteRule index.php?=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}

If the three `RewriteCond`s are all right, it will execute the `RewriteRule` line. What does the rule mean?

Comment: This isn't perl, this is just apache configuration.

Comment: that looks like a .htaccess did you try googling any of the key words. Like RewriteCond

Comment: austinbv, have read some tutorial, but still don't know some part of those lines. could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

These lines are not regular expressions but [mod_rewrite directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

To understand what this ruleset does, you need to know [how a ruleset is processed internalls](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) and what the directives mean. For the latter you should check the corresponding description in the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Doing that, you should see that the `RewriteRule` is probably not how it was intended. Because the first argument (i.e. `index.php?=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`) is interpreted as regular expression pattern and the second as substitution (i.e. `[L]`). And that doesn’t make sense. It should probably read something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php?=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

So I’m assuming the following ruleset instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %1/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ index.php?=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

This ruleset can be interpreted as follows:

> If
>
> - the pattern `^` matches the given request URI path
> - **and** `^www\.(.*)$` matches the value of *HTTP_HOST*
> - **and** the match of the first subpattern (i.e. `%1`) of the previous successful `RewriteCond` pattern matching concatenated with `/` and the value of *REQUEST_FILENAME* can be mapped onto an existing regular file (i.e. `-f`)
> - **and** can also be mapped onto an existing directory (i.e. `-d`),
>
> then rewrite the request internally to `index.php?=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and make this the last rule in the current processing (i.e. *L* flag).

But this rule is nonsense. Because a request cannot be mapped on both an existing regular file *and* an existing directory at the same time. Furthermore, *REQUEST_FILENAME* is an absolute filesystem path; prepending something like a domain suffix to it will make it invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The rules rewrite an [HTTP GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to use a query string for PHP.

For example, it turns

```
domain.com/page/1/
```

into

```
domain.com?page=1
```

Comment: @zhuanzhou: you really ought to just read the documentation and figure out how it works yourself.  We aren't going to do everything for you.  If you come to an understanding of .htaccess rewrite rules and still have a question about how some part of it works, then you can come back.

Comment: siride, i have read some tutorial, but still don't know some part of those lines. could you explain it to me?